# Appending only new values from a dataframe to another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very huge data frame with me. I have also a small data frame with me.

Both of those data frames will have same columns.

The small data frame will have some rows that are already present in the big data frame. I want to append the small data frame to big one such that there will be no duplicates in the big data frame.

I can append simply and then remove the duplicates. But this will lead to wastage of memory to keep the duplicated data frame in the memory.

Is there any other method that can be used efficiently to solve this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data**:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3,8,4,9]})
```

Use merge to get unique rows,

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, how='left', indicator=True)

    a     _merge
0   3       both
1   8  left_only
2   4       both
3   9  left_only
```

Now, select rows with `'left_only'`,

```
df3 =df3[df3._merge == 'left_only'].iloc[:,:-1]
```

Finally, append them.

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df3], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: The solution will work, but it will lead to auxilary memory usage.

Comment: You can't have best of both. There exists a trade off. Through this, atleast a bigger memory spike won't occur.

Answer (score 3):

What about *isin*?

**Data:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3,4,9]})
```

**Code:**

```
df1.append(df2[df2.isin(df1) == False])
```

**Output:**

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
6  7
0  3
1  4
2  9
```

Comment: There are mutliple columns to check. As i told, my dataframe is huge around 10G. This will take a lot of time to run